# I'm trying to add words to an array from a text input but it is coming back as an "Uncaught TypeError"

Tags: javascript, arrays, user-input

This is the error message - `"<a class='gotoLine' href='#76:28'>76:28</a> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementId  is not a function"`

I have two text inputs being combined before being inserted into an array

This is the code that gave the error -

HTML:

```
<p>
Quote:
  <input type="text" id = quoteWords>
</p>
<p>
  Name:
  <input type="text" id = quoteName>
</p>
<button id=submitButton><strong>Submit</strong></button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var button = document.getElementById("submitButton");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
var customQuote1 = document.getElementId("quoteWords");
var customQuote2 = document.getElementId("quoteName");
quote.push(customQuote1 + "<p>-" + customQuote2 + "</p>");
});
```

I

Comment: I guess you have a typo there and meant `getElementById` and not `getElementId`. Also - what is `quote`?

Answer (score 0):

As the comment underneath your question already stated. It's most likely that you have a typo and it's `getElementById`instead of `getElementId`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around your inputs' id attributes.